# Is is more efficient to call dispatch_async once or multiple times

Tags: objective-c, multithreading, cocoa-touch

I am trying to understand the run loop. Which is the best way to code this?

```
for (UIView *view in self.viewSet) { 
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
        [view removeFromSuperview];
    });
}
```

or

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
    for (UIView *view in self.viewSet) { 
        [view removeFromSuperview];
    }
});
```

Comment: I think looping through subviews doesn't need to be run on main thread. Only UI operations like removeFromSuperView needs to be run on main thread.

Comment: The question having been asked suggests the problem has not really been examined, since (ignoring the specifics of GCD and the great points made below), the difference between these two options is _not_ pinned on the efficiency of calling `dispatch_get_main_queue()`, that's only one factor. The effect of calling `dispatch_async()` is another since the number of calls to that also changes with this implementation change. Then when we consider what each of these calls do, intuitively thinking, `dispatch_async()` will have a _lot_ more overhead than `dispatch_get_main_queue()`, so focus on that.

Comment: @mah You are correct! The title is corrected to ask the real question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first one

```
for (UIView *view in self.viewSet) { 
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
        [view removeFromSuperview];
    });
}
```

queues up a bunch of `[view removeFromSuperview]` calls on the main thread. After the loop is over, they are executed one at a time. Each call is stuck waiting until the main queue clears, like a train waiting to pull into a station.

The second one

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
    for (UIView *view in self.viewSet) { 
        [view removeFromSuperview];
    }
});
```

queues just *one* thing onto the main thread, namely the whole loop. As soon as the main thread is free, a single piece of code runs, in which all the views are removed, kaboom.

Comment: so the second one is more faster than first one ?

Comment: Does the second one 'clog up' the run loop?

Comment: Matt, would you mind adding that last comment to your answer? So, it is ok to pile the whole lot of `-removeFromSuperview` on GCD?

Comment: @matt Downright dangerous?  The `view` is strongly held by the block and a view removed from the superview by some other mechanism indicates a bug elsewhere and multiple calls to removeFromSuperview are documented as being, effectively, a no-op.

Answer (score 4):

To answer the question specifically, it breaks down into the size of units of work.    If you dispatch a really large chunk of work to the main thread, then that large chunk will block the main thread for the entire time it is processing.  If you dispatch a bunch really small chunks of work to the main thread, then the main thread will interleave processing of the chunks of work with processing of other events which will make your app slightly less efficient, but overall more responsive.

*However*, in the context of the question asked, neither `dispatch_async()` pattern is likely to be what you really want.  You really shouldn't be removing a ton of views from any superview, whether it be all at once or interleaved on the main queue.

Instead, you should have a container view that contains the views that need to be swapped out-- potentially managed by a view controller-- and you should have *one* `removeFromSuperview` that removes that container.   Once removed, then there really shouldn't be a need to manually remove any of the container views as you should have defined the retain/weak ownership rules such that you don't have cycles through view -> subview relationships.

Or, succinctly:

```
dispatch_async(.. main queue .., ^{
    [_myContainerView removeFromSuperview];
});
```

In an ideal world, that `removeFromSuperview` would remove the last reference to `_myContainerView` and then it'd automatically tear down the hierarchy of subviews as the `UIKit` sees fit.

Comment: The 3rd paragraph has a great point. Thank you for adding to your answer.

Comment: @David In the context of the question, whether you were to use a loop of individual calls to dispatch_async() or a single call to dispatch_async() with the loop in it is irrelevant.   It is the same amount of work either way and creating a couple of dozen (likely a lot less) blocks is pretty much irrelevant.  The whole thing doesn't matter until you measure a performance issue anyway.